# Cakephp application development scope

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I want to separate my cakephp application in users authentications... I have created authentication key of 50 digits as boolean. that is `10111...` in this way.. Now I wanna separate my application accordingly. Suppose for blog post. I want to access to view post if users first authentication digit is `1`, If my post is private then I need to authenticate it using digit `2`. For any other status of my post suppose private I wanna again check an action of digit. What should I do with this scope.? Is it better way to go with...

Second I want to have common function. I have just taken example of simple controller post I wanna do it for most of my models and controllers. How can I make single inbuilt function for all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create all these rules in your AppControllers `Authorize()` method, assuming you are using the AuthComponent and Controller as your auth method.